# Laravel relationships for sports fixtures

Tags: laravel

So, I am creating a results website for boxing, I am trying to get a boxers past results, but am struggling with relationships...

For example, a boxer can have many events (a fight), and have 1 result (a win, draw or loss), and 1 opponent. I am trying to display all of the boxers results, with the opponents information

So, I have an event with the structure (can add a relationship id if needed)

```
    Schema::create('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->date('date');
        $table->string('location');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

I have a boxer table

```
    Schema::create('boxers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('status');
        $table->string('division');
        $table->string('stance');
        $table->date('dob');
        $table->integer('height');
        $table->string('nationality');
        $table->string('residence');
        $table->string('birthplace');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

and the results

```
    Schema::create('results', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('event_id');
        $table->string('result');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

What would I need to add and change to get a relationship to work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events typically `hasMany` fights (many fights on a card), each fight `hasMany` (two) athletes.  So your fight/athlete relationship would be many-to-many (fighters have many fights throughout their career).  You'll create a pivot table `athletes_fights` which will have `fight_id` and  `athlete_id` columns.  Additionally, this pivot table could have a `winner_id` and a `draw` column.  Draw could default to 0, 1 if the fight is a draw.  It could also have `win_method` (could even create another table for this and make it `win_method_id`), `win_round`, `win_time`.

Check out the relationships section in the Laravel docs, if you haven't already.

So your model would be..
`Event`
`Fight`
`Athlete`